# inconsistency between CPU/GPU results and GPU/GPU with the same algorithm using chained or `||`

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to set values of an array to a certain value; all is as if I have a 2D image and I set pixels under a rectangle to a certain value. Sometimes the rectangle is fully inside the image, sometime it's not.

[image: example]

I tried to do this with cuda, it works well when the rectangle is fully inside, but otherwise, it work only when the rectangle is too far with both x and y axis (bottom right configuration, further).

I describe the rectangle with this:

```
template <class T>
struct ROIRect
{
    T X{};
    T Y{};
    T W{};
    T H{};

    ROIRect() = default;
    ROIRect(T x, T y, T w, T h);
};
```

The work is done by the following functions. The putative faulty one is `setMask`.

```
template <class T>
T* GetHostArray(size_t size)
{
    size_t sizeBytes = size * sizeof(T);
    T* array_h = (T*)malloc(sizeBytes);
    if (array_h != nullptr)
        memset(array_h, 0, sizeBytes);
    return array_h;
}

template <class T>
auto GetPitched_ImFlat2D() -> cudaPitchedPtr
{
    cudaPitchedPtr p{};
    p.xsize = w * c * sizeof(T);
    p.ysize = h;
    CheckCudaErrors(cudaMallocPitch(&p.ptr, &p.pitch, p.xsize, p.ysize));
    CheckCudaErrors(cudaMemset2D(p.ptr, p.pitch, 0, p.xsize, p.ysize));
    return p;
}

namespace MasksKernels
{
    template <class T>
    __device__ T* GetRow(const cudaPitchedPtr& mask, size_t y) { return (T*)((uchar*)mask.ptr + y * mask.pitch); }

    __global__ void setMask(cudaPitchedPtr mask, ROIRect<int> sh, uchar value, int w)
    {
        uint x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        uint y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
        if (y >= mask.ysize || x >= w) return;

        if (x < sh.X || x >= sh.X + sh.W ||
            y < sh.Y || y >= sh.Y + sh.H) return;

        auto O = GetRow<uchar>(mask, y);
        O[x] = value;
    }
}

void SetMaskCPU(int w, int h, const ROIRect<int>& sh, uchar value, const string& filename)
{
    auto m = GetHostArray<uchar>(w*h);
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        {
            if (x < sh.X || x >= sh.X + sh.W ||
                y < sh.Y || y >= sh.Y + sh.H) continue;
            m[y * w + x] = value;
        }
    // WriteImage(filename, m); //pseudo code
}

template<class T>
auto DownloadFromPitched2D_1C(cudaPitchedPtr p1C, T*& dest) -> void
{
    uint wBytes = w*sizeof(T);
    uint dPitch = wBytes ;
    CheckCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy2D(dest, dPitch, p1C.ptr, p1C.pitch, wBytes, h, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
}
    
ROIRect sh{}; // the region fo interest
int w; // width of the image
int h; // height of the image
inc c{1}; // colors
dim3 BlockSize; // BlockSize = {x=8 y=4 z=1 }
dim3 GridSize; // GridSize = {x=25 y=125 z=1 }

void SetMaskCu(int value, const ShRect& sh, const cudaPitchedPtr& pbg, const string& filename)
{
    MasksKernels::setMask << <GridSize, BlockSize >> > (pbg, sh, value, w);
    CheckCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());

    auto harray = GetHostArray<uchar>(w*h);
    DownloadFromPitched2D_1C(pbg, harray);

    //pseudo code
    //WriteImage(filename, harray);
}

int main()
{
    w = 200;
    h = 500;
    int border = 100;
    sh.W = w - border;
    sh.H = h - border;
    sh.X = -sh.W / 2; // I center the rectangle over a corner of the image
    sh.Y = -sh.H / 2;

    // CPU case
    SetMaskCPU(w, h, sh, 255, "resultCPU.jpg");

    // GPU case
    auto pitchedArray = GetPitched_ImFlat2D<uchar>();
    SetMaskCu(255, sh, pitchedArray, "resultCu.jpg");
}
```

The lines in `setMask`:

```
        if (x < sh.X || x >= sh.X + sh.W ||
            y < sh.Y || y >= sh.Y + sh.H) return;
```

were tested correct with the CPU case, but it does not work fully with the GPU case; individual comparison work fine alone, but cease to give the give result when together when chained with the `||`.
More specifically:

```
if (x < sh.X) return; //work well alone

if (x >= sh.X + sh.W) return; //work well alone

if (y < sh.Y) return; //work well alone

if (y >= sh.Y + sh.H) return; //work well alone
```

I do not see any reason for the results to be inconsistents when I use the chained  or `||`.

Results from CPU executions:

[image: cpu results]

Results from GPU executions (full black images are wrong):

[image: gpu results]

With `compute-sanitizer.bat`, I got zero error:

```
> ========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
> ========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

Is the cause the chained or `||` ? if so why ? and why does it work *sometimes* ? how do I get the expected logic / results with cuda ?

Comment: Can you try running it with compute-sanitizer?

Comment: @DamirTenishev I edited to specify w,h,c (width, height, colors of the image). I adapted the repro to make it shorter, actually those are (thread safe) fields of the class in the real project, but I'm trying to make it shorter for SO. Using break points, I see that they are correct.

Comment: @AnisLadram I updated the OP, zero error with cuda and compute-sanitizer.

Comment: @DamirTenishev uchar is an alias for unsigned char. I do not think because no unicode is involved in the image computation, and for several inital conditions (only one of the chained comparisons and bottom right) are exactly correct (matching the CPU result). I'll share a project on github to help.

Comment: @Soleil, just out of curiosity to make my answers more useful. What made the answer from sgarizvi so much better that you accepted it though my answer came earlier (2 mins don’t count, but, anyway, not later) and, as for me, more comprehensive (confirmed by more votes, as well)? (No intention to change your mind). Is it because it is shorter or there is another reason I am missing?

Comment: @DamirTenishev I needed only to change the index from uint to int in the kernel. Unlike what you developed ROIRect was using int already so it was not the problem as you claimed. But indeed your solution is more complete and came earlier. I switched the acceptation ;)

Comment: @Soleil, I see; thanks for the explanation. You are correct here, the problem that I couldn't have known this from the code provided, that's why I included both options (see your core with the `ROIRect sh{};` which assumes that the ROIRect template definition should have a default `int` type, then). Anyway, I fixed the answer so that it could help the others; this was the only intention of my question, not altering your decision. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When comparing signed with unsigned, the compiler converts the signed value to unsigned.

The problem is with

```
    sh.X = -sh.W / 2; // I center the rectangle over a corner of the image
    sh.Y = -sh.H / 2;
```

taking into account that `ROIRect<int>` instantiated with int you have troubles later with the:

```
    uint x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    uint y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
```

and your

```
    if (x < sh.X || x >= sh.X + sh.W ||
        y < sh.Y || y >= sh.Y + sh.H) return;
```

With this OR combination if one of comparisons fails (by the mistake above), you are going to check another one in hope that at least it would work (logic of OR operator) and if it works, your code returns. When you separate the conditions into many if operators, your code returns immediately.

The **solution** is to use

```
ROIRect<int> sh{};
```

and

```
int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the data types of the indices `x` and `y`. See how the `SetMaskCPU` has type `int` while the `setMask` kernel has type `uint` for x and y. Observe the pattern in the incorrect results. Any pattern which encounters a negative index results in incorrect result. So only the `bottomRight` is correct and rest are incorrect. This is due to implicit type conversion of `int` to `uint` while performing comparison.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12854538/1231073) is a similar problem which I encountered in the past.

**Solution:**

In the `setMask` kernel, change the type of `x` and `y` to `int`.

Comment: Indeed. IJW if I dare to say.

Comment: ...but how do you explain I did not see the "bug" (the result was as expected) when I use only one of the four chained comparisons in the kernel and using unsigned indexes ?

Comment: @Soleil, please see my updated answer for the explanation.